# Tree root damage

Tags: trees

Having a patio put in and the guys hit a root on a 30-40' tree located about 10' away.  How should they proceed to cover the root and what damage might occur to the tree?

Comment: Please clarify your question - what do you mean by 'hit' a root (damaged it? cut it? exposed it?) and if its not damaged, why is it not possible to rebury it under soil? How big is this root - is the patio lower than the root? Photos?

Comment: Welcome Denise! We definitely want to help you, but we need some more details. Bamboo and Stormy have both asked some important questions. Would you please add the information into your question by pressing [edit]? Since you're new, have a look around our [help] to see how the site works. [Ask] is a great place to start. This question might get put on hold unless we hear back from you. [This page](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) explains that. You'll still have time to edit it, though, and we hope you do!

Answer (score 0):

Need to include a picture to identify what tree you have.  *To ruin just one big root should be no worry.*  If your patio is concrete then we need to know type of tree and whether that tree needs for pH. Concrete use for foundations, walkways, patios greatly influences soil pH.  If you send pictures we could help do some pruning to balance the root damage.  How long have you had this tree? (Maybe this should be a comment, not an 'answer'...), take pictures of patio, environment and tree all together, close ups of base of tree, close ups of leaves, buds, bark...is there lawn around this tree?  Is there a cleared circle of lawn, weeds, plants around the base of the tree, what are you using for mulch?  Fertilizer?